# facebook like button and IE8: errors javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

When I add some like buttons to my sites, these look ok with Firefox and Chrome, but generate errors in IE8 an do not display at all
ex:
http://www.dialogoo.com
error:

***Message : Object doesn't support this property or method**
line : 31
Caractère : 3134
Code : 0
URI : http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1

**Message : Object doesn't support this property or method**
Line : 31
Caractère : 3134
Code : 0
URI : http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1
Agent utilisateur : Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9

*Accept-encode:  (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.2; chromeframe/16.0.912.75; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)
Horodateur : Fri, 6 Jan 2012 09:26:22 UTC**

Any idea on how to fix that  on IE8 ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

1. Include Facebook's namespace in your HTML tag: `<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">`
2. Use a channelURL as described [in the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)